# How does Criteria and HQL query return values

Tags: java, hibernate

guys I would like to ask you a simple question.
Im creating two the same queries, one with criteria and one with HQL.

HQL example

```
@Override
public List<Object[]> getAllLoginHQL() {
    Query<Object[]> query = manager.getSession()
            .createQuery("select user.firstName from User user",Object[].class);
    return query.getResultList();
}
```

Criteria example:

```
@Override
public List<User> getAllLoginCriteria() {
    Criteria criteria = manager.getSession()
            .createCriteria(User.class)
            .setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
                    .add(Projections.property("firstName"), "firstName"))
            .setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(User.class));

    return criteria.list();
}
```

As you can see, both queries do the same thing, but when I tried to do create HQL query with return type `List<User>`, I got exception with message that return type of this query is `List<String>`.
I would like to know why Criteria can return whole object(with null inside), even when Im asking for one/two columns and HQL is returning only specific columns?

This HQL query, gives exception

```
@Override
public List<User> getAllLoginHQL() {
    Query<User> query = manager.getSession()
            .createQuery("select user.firstName from User user",User.class);
    return query.getResultList();
}
```

Exception message:

```
Type specified for TypedQuery  is incompatible with query return type [class java.lang.String]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look [here](http://in.relation.to/2006/03/17/hibernate-32-transformers-for-hql-and-sql/#H-HQLTransformers)

The spec says you can accomplish that by setting a ResultTransformer.

It would be something like this:

```
   manager.getSession()
            .createQuery("select user.firstName from User user",Object[].class)
            .setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(User.class))
            .getResultList();
```